# Is it safe to use ngx permissions in angular for acl management?

Tags: angular, acl

I am using angular 6 and I want to control access of users. As far as I know it is recommended to manage acl in the backend but, angular has some packeges such as [ngx permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions) to do it in frontend. Is it safe to use its features? Or I'm in a wrong foot!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is **not safe** to only manage your security in your front-end application.

If you have an Angular application, it is very likely that it connects to some back-end API, which must be secured.

Let's take a simple example.

- You have a Save button
- When clicking the Save button, it calls your API to create or update a record

You can easily hide the Save button or prevent the calls to your API, possibly using ngx permissions.

However nothing prevents the user to find out that the button is making that call and perform the call outside of your application. So your API must be secured.

"Securing" your front-end application is only a mean to provide a better user experience.

There is also a [warning](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions#introduction) mentioned by the author if ngx-permissions

Answer (score 1):

If your angular app does have no connection to a backend (REST service) then it would be ok - then it is the only way. But if you are connected to some sort of service that is published via an interface you should build some security there too.